# C# curly brackets within method body

Tags: c#, branch, brackets

**Note:** This is more of a question for my understanding.

Today I stumbled upon a structure within C# which I had not seen before.
While typing and talking to a colleague, I mistakenly added (curly) brackets within my method body, and only noticed after compiling, and the compiler didn't show me any warnings or errors.

```
#region Determine if update is newer than current version

{
    var tmpMetaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(Path.Combine(plugin.FullName, METADATA_FILE_NAME));
    if (tmpMetaData.GetValue(METADATA_KEY_APP_VER) == metaData.GetValue(METADATA_KEY_APP_VER)) {
        WriteLine("The currently installed version of {0} is identical to the version found in the update pak...");
        WriteLine("This update will be ignored.");
        continue;
    }
}

#endregion
```

After googling for a while and not finding anything concrete, but some vague information about branching in C#, I gathered that this construct must be one form of branching.

I've seen similar in Java, however that is object initialization.

I cannot access the variable within this block, which further strengthens my theory.

Can anyone confirm my theory, or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That didn't show up with my google searches. Explains a lot.